# Restful webservice with jersey 2.0 without maven

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey, jersey-client, jersey-2.0

Can anybody tell me how to make a restful web service with Jersey 2.0 by not using maven. I have searched everywhere and found tutorial for Jersey1.x versions but not for 2.0. Please help

Comment: What build tool do you want to use?

Comment: I am using eclipse only

Comment: Eclipse is an IDE, not a build tool. If you don't want to use Maven, you probably use Ant, or Gradle, ... Which of these do you use? Which of these does *Eclipse* use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer

```
package com.hellowebservice;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

@GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello Jersey";
  }

  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  public String sayXMLHello() {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
  }

  // This method is called if HTML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
  }

}
```

Web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
   <display-name>FirstRestWebService</display-name>
    <servlet>
   <display-name>Rest Servlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
       <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
           <param-value>com.hellowebservice.MyApplication</param-value>
            </init-param>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

MyApplication.java

```
package com.hellowebservice;
   import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;


   public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
      public MyApplication() {
          packages("com.hellowebservice");
    }
   }
```

run with localhost:8080/FirstRestWebService/rest/hello

Comment: What are the included JARs ? Have you managed to return complex objects instead of strings ?

Comment: I tried this example but when i hit the URL it says "HTTP Status 404 - /FirstRestWebService/rest/hello"

Comment: can you clarify pls, what means run with "localhost..." where is the server that starts? where is the main method?

Comment: Can anyone explain the need for MyApplication.java file?

Answer (score 4):

We provide detail answere based on the user answer user2629427. we checked this on windows 7.

Requirement: (brackets indicate version which this example is tested)

- tomcat (8 zip version)
- jersey (2.x)

Unzip the tomcat & create a below folder structure in tomcat's 'webapps' folder (folder names are case sensitive).

```
abc
  |___ WEB-INF
      |____ classes
      |____ lib
```

Put 'Hello.java' and 'MyApplication.java' into 'classes' folder and 'web.xml' into 'WEB-INF' folder.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"          
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" 
    version="3.1">  

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.king.MyApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Myapplication.java

```
package com.king;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        packages("com.king");
    }
}
```

Hello.java

```
package com.king;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey";
    }

    // This method is called if XML is request
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><hello>Hello Jersey</hello>";
    }

    // This method is called if HTML is request
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html><title>Hi Jersey</title><body><h1>Hello Jersey this is laksys</body></h1></html>";
    }
}
```

Unzip jersey and copy all jar files from  api, ext, and lib (not folders) into your apps 'lib' folder.

Now compile the two java files using following command

```
D:\apache-tc-8\webapps\abc\WEB-INF\classes>javac -d . -cp ..\lib\javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar;..\lib\jersey-server.jar;..\l ib\jersey-common.jar *.java
```

Next run the tomcat server

```
D:\apache-tc-8\bin>startup
```

In browser address bar type this: http://localhost:8080/abc/rest/hello

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the previous answer. If you aren't using Maven and just building using Eclipse with a Dynamic Web Project and deploying to web app server like Tomcat.

Just download the Jersey JAX-RS 2.0 RI bundle [Jersey Downloads](https://jersey.java.net/download.html), unzip and add all the jars in the lib, api and ext folders to your build path. (I tried without ext jars but got classnotfound when starting the server).

Also add all the jars to the Deployment Assembly of your Dynamic Web Project so they get automatically copied to the WEB-INF/lib directory when deployed to your web app server. Along with the code & web.xml in the above answer, you should have a RESTful api using Jersey 2 up and running.